# Скорость вывода текста в pascal

Tags: pascal

Нужно выдавать пользователю много текста. Можно ли сделать отрезки времени в секундах между очередным writeln?
Где-то слышал, что можно выводить текст так, как будто он печатается прямо сейчас, а не сплошником в один миг, такое возможно?

Comment: что вам мешает использовать `delay` / `sleep`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как-будто печатается прямо сейчас:

```
var
  s: string;

begin
  read(s);
  for var i := 1 to length(s) do
  begin
    write(s[i]);
    sleep(50);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: лучше сделать задержку случайной

Comment: Ну, это дело вкуса